# Why do i always get a whole black picture which screenshoot by GLSurfaceView?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap, glsurfaceview, egl

I use the `GLSurfaceView` as the view to display the camera preview data. I use `createBitmapFromGLSurface` aim at grabPixels and save it to `Bitmap`.

However, I always get a whole black picture after save the bitmap to file. Where am i wrong?

Following is my code snippet.

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    if (mIsNeedCaptureFrame) {
        mIsNeedCaptureFrame = false;
        createBitmapFromGLSurface(width, height);
    }
}

private void createBitmapFromGLSurface(int w, int h) {
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(w * h * 4);
    buf.position(0);
    buf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, w, h,
            GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf);
    buf.rewind();

    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buf);

    Log.i(TAG, "createBitmapFromGLSurface w:" + w + ",h:" + h);
    mFrameCapturedCallback.onFrameCaptured(bmp);
}
```

Update:

```
public void captureFrame(FrameCapturedCallback callback) {
    mIsNeedCaptureFrame = true;
    mCallback = callback;
}

public void takeScreenshot() {
    final int width = mIncomingWidth;
    final int height = mIncomingHeight;
    EglCore eglCore = new EglCore(EGL14.eglGetCurrentContext(), EglCore.FLAG_RECORDABLE);
    OffscreenSurface surface = new OffscreenSurface(eglCore, width, height);
    surface.makeCurrent();
    Bitmap bitmap = surface.captureFrame();

    for (int x = 0, y = 0; x < 100; x++, y++) {
        Log.i(TAG, "getPixel:" + bitmap.getPixel(x, y));
    }
    surface.release();
    eglCore.release();
    mCallback.onFrameCaptured(bitmap);
}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

    mSurfaceTexture.updateTexImage();

    if (mIsNeedCaptureFrame) {
        mIsNeedCaptureFrame = false;
        takeScreenshot();
        return;
    }
    ....
 }
```

The logs are following:

```
getPixel:0
getPixel:0
getPixel:0
getPixel:0
getPixel:0
getPixel:0
getPixel:0
getPixel:0
getPixel:0
getPixel:0
getPixel:0
...
```

Comment: I suspect someone reflexively downvoted a "why can't I screen-shot SurfaceView" question, expecting it to be the usual attempt to grab the screen with the View render cache. But that's not what you're doing, and it's failing for an entirely different reason. I gave +1 for asking something new. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't work.

To understand why, bear in mind that a SurfaceView Surface is a queue of buffers with a producer-consumer relationship.  When displaying camera preview data, the Camera is the producer, and the system compositor (SurfaceFlinger) is the consumer.  Only the producer can send data to the Surface -- there can be only one producer at a time -- and only the consumer can examine buffers from the Surface.

If you were drawing on the Surface yourself, so your app would be the producer, you would be able to see what you've drawn, but only while in`onDrawFrame()`.  When it returns, GLSurfaceView calls `eglSwapBuffers()`, and the frame you've drawn is sent off to the consumer.  (Technically, because the buffers are in a pool and are re-used, you *can* read frames outside `onDrawFrame()`; but what you're reading would be stale data from 1-2 frames back, not the one you just drew.)

What you're doing here is reading data from an EGLSurface that has never been drawn on and isn't connected to the SurfaceView.  That's why it's always reading black.  The Camera doesn't "draw" the preview, it just takes a buffer of YUV data and shoves it into the BufferQueue.

If you want to show the preview and capture frames using GLSurfaceView, see the "show + capture camera" example in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika).  You can replace the MediaCodec code with a `glReadPixels()` (see `EglSurfaceBase.saveFrame()`, which looks very much like what you have).

Comment: BTW, is it possible that both MediaCodec code and Frame capture code exist simultaneously ？In Grafika, i can't capture frame as the encoder will be released after stopRecording. I want to capture frame all the time during the camera active.

Comment: The "show + capture camera" example is receiving frames from Camera with a SurfaceTexture. It then renders the SurfaceTexture to the GLSurfaceView and, if active, to the video encoder. You can send that frame to as many destinations as you want. For a simple frame-grab you can use an off-screen pbuffer -- render to it, then `glReadPixels()` from it. (See gles/OffscreenSurface.java)

Comment: If I use `OffscreenSurface` to grab frame and save to file, what point should i highlight? I do it as these steps: 1. construct `EglCore`: `eglCore = new EglCore(null, 0);` 2. construct `OffscreenSurface`: `surface = new OffscreenSurface(eglCore, mWidth, mHeight);` 3. saveframe: `surface.saveFrame()`. But i got a whole white picture. It seems i have missed something.

Comment: I think you're missing 2.5. draw on the surface. Draw on it the same way you would any other surface: make it current, issue GLES commands. Not sure why it's coming out white.

Comment: What's the "missing 2.5." ?

Comment: Between `surface.makeCurrent()` and `surface.saveFrame()`, you need to draw something on the surface. If you're following "show + capture camera", that would be `mSurfaceTexture.getTransformMatrix(mSTMatrix); mFullScreen.drawFrame(mTextureId, mSTMatrix);`. This assumes that, on entry, the EGL context is the one from the SurfaceTexture. You may also want to switch the EGL context back after you're done saving the frame.

Comment: I got a error "eglMakeCurrent:776 error 3002 (EGL_BAD_ACCESS)" when switch the context back. So how to "switch the EGL context back" ? Thanks.

Comment: Call `makeCurrent()` on the other surface. If you're switching back to the GLSurfaceView's surface, you can save/restore it the way the Android Breakout patch does (http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/0001-Record-game-into-.mp4.patch) -- see `saveRenderState()` and `restoreRenderState()`.